# Which action does the cost of Riposte apply to?

Tags: numenera

The fifth tier glaive ability Riposte (Character Options, p. 9) has the cost of 6 Speed points, and is an enabler. Following a successful defence roll,  it allows either an immediate counter-attack, or a delayed asset to a subsequent attack.

The Corebook makes it clear that enablers are not actions in themselves, but either function constantly, or are parts of other actions (p 25), and Riposte is clearly the latter type.

But my question is - which action does Riposte apply to: the defence action which has just happened, or the (counter-)attack which is about to happen? This makes a difference in terms of using Edge and Effort for the defence or attack actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pay 6 Speed to gain the benefits of the Riposte ability, which are one of the following:

- An immediate counter-attack.
- An asset on your next action.

The enabler happens **after** a successful defense. This mean that the 6 Speed must be paid after the defense action that triggeted the enabler.

If you decide to make an immediate attack, your speed edge is already reduced by using the Riposte ability. If you decide to wait until your next action, your Speed edge is reset and you can use it again for this action.

Comment: That makes the most sense, thank you. It was great you replied so quickly too, as we were able to use your interpretation straight away during our gaming session.